# Android: two pages activity

Tags: android

Simple question:

I want an activity to have two or multiple pages,like a launcher does.

I think this should be done with **fragments** but I am a newbie developer,so I don't have much idea on working this with fragments.

Basically the user swipes right or left to change the "page", any ideas?

Comment: try to work on view pager examples..you will get an idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that a ViewPager will fit yout needs:

[Using ViewPager for Screen Slides](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html)

Your Activity will contain a Viewpager, wich will hold several Fragments for the Pages you want to display. Navigationg the pages by swiping left and right will be handled automatcally.

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to use a [ViewSwitcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewSwitcher.html). You can define multiple views inside a single Layout XML file and switch the views when the user swipes left or right.

Comment: Can I switch fragments?